# why my object don't change position when i add value

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```
<hmtl>
<head>
<!--<script src='main.js'></script>-->
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='myCanvas'> </canvas>
<script>
function shape(x,y){
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect( this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
}
}
var sqr=new shape(100,100)
sqr.x+=100
</script>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

why i add 100 to x and hope its positon will be (200,100) but when i open live sever it position still remain (100,100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because it will only change the value of x, you have to draw it again on the canvas and before drawing again we have to clear canvas using clearRect**

```js
<html>
   <head>
      <!--<script src='main.js'></script>-->
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id='myCanvas'> </canvas>
      <script>
         function shape(x,y){
              this.x=x;
              this.y=y;
              var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
              var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
              this.draw = ()=>{
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
              ctx.fillRect( this.x, this.y, 50, 50);
              ctx.stroke();
            }
         }
         var sqr=new shape(100,100)
         sqr.draw();
         sqr.x+=-100
         sqr.draw();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```